# Mysql GROUP BY DATE from text column

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have a DB with a text column that will store the date and time as DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS (example: 27-11-2015 17:01:53).

Now I would like to make some stats with PHP, but I just can't solve the problem with dates.

I would like to count all results that have the same day (DD/MM/YYYY) despite the hour created.

I've already tryed many solutions but none works.

By best attempt was this one, but gives me NULL as the date:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATECOLUMN, '%d/%m/%Y'), COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(DATECOLUMN, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

I would like to make the search in interval based too and I would like some help in searchings for a date interval this way as the "normal" way doesn't work.  Using the below code will not work to make intervals.

```
WHERE DATE(DATECOLUM) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Could someone help me trying to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Fix the column to store dates in the correct format.  Don't use strings to store values when the database knows the right way to store them.

Comment: The code is already done. Will I really need to change my code in a bunch of files? There isn't really any way to do it?

Comment: There is no obligation on your part to use an RDBMS, but seeing as you appear to want to use one...

Comment: The problem is third party interaction that reads the date as DD/MM/YYYY, so even I change the date form in my files, the third party will now work as I don't have access to it. There's not really another way to do it?

Comment: Your format -> `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` does not match your `example: 27-11-2015 17:01:53`. Last time I checked `/`!=`-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT date_format(str_to_date(DATECOLUMN, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') AS MyDate, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY MyDate
```

For interval and group you can try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MyDate
FROM TABLE, (
    SELECT date_format(str_to_date(DATECOLUMN, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') AS MyDate
    FROM TABLE) Tmp 
WHERE date_format(str_to_date(MyDate, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY MyDate
```

Comment: And it's possible to create an interval, make it search for last 7 days for example with the new date (DD/MM/YYYY) ?

Comment: @Tiago I added another query

Comment: I've made some changes due to my data information and it works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I think I found the solution and it's working pretty good. For those what would need it in future:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(DATEC_OLUMN , "%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S"), "%d/%m/%y") AS date, 
       COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_COLUMN, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S"), "%d/%m/%y")
```

The code above will transform my text column string in **DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS to DD/MM/YYYY** and will group it and count it by date